# Need an associative array but with the same keys for NuSoap

Tags: php, arrays, nusoap

I need to make a repeating array for this part of xml as an array, but as you can see there is a repeating item here.

```
    <orderItems>
      <OrderItemRequest>
        <line_id>int</line_id>
        <product_id>string</product_id>
        <product_variant_id>string</product_variant_id>
        <product_desc>string</product_desc>
        <quantity>int</quantity>
        <variant_desc>string</variant_desc>
        <item_total>decimal</item_total>
      </OrderItemRequest>
      <OrderItemRequest>
        <line_id>int</line_id>
        <product_id>string</product_id>
        <product_variant_id>string</product_variant_id>
        <product_desc>string</product_desc>
        <quantity>int</quantity>
        <variant_desc>string</variant_desc>
        <item_total>decimal</item_total>
      </OrderItemRequest>
    </orderItems>
```

This is what I had tried to do:

```
$orderItemRequest = "";

foreach($requestArray as $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        $orderItemRequest .= $comma."<$key>";

        foreach ($val as $key2 => $val2) {
            $orderItemRequest .= "<$key2>$val2</$key2>";
        }

        $orderItemRequest .= "</$key>";
    }
}

array('carrier_code' => 'UPS',
'dob' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dob)),
'creditcard_number' => $CCNumber,
'card_type' => $CCType,
'card_expire_date' => $CCExpireMonth."/".$CCExpireYear,
'CV_Code' => $CCSecurity,
'Customer_Email' => $email,
'orderItems' => $orderItemRequest,
'ChallengeQuestion' => '',
'ChallengeAnswer' => '',
'localeSetting' => '',
'ignoreAddressValidation' => '1',
'auth_code' => '',
'affiliate_code' => '');
```

I've tried to insert the xml directly as the value of `orderItems` but get the error: `nusoap_client: got wsdl error: phpType is struct, but value is not an array: see debug output for details`.

Here is the last bit of the debug info:

2013

```
-04-27 05:22:42.816864 wsdl: in serializeType: name=orderItems, type=http://phepartnerws/:ArrayOfOrderItemRequest, use=literal, encodingStyle=, unqualified=qualified
value=string(845) "<OrderItemRequest><line_id>0</line_id><product_id>005K</product_id><product_variant_id>005K</product_variant_id><product_desc>TANTRIC AURA MASSAGER</product_desc><variant_desc>TANTRIC AURA MASSAGER</variant_desc><quantity>1</quantity><item_total>24.98</item_total></OrderItemRequest><OrderItemRequest><line_id>1</line_id><product_id>754</product_id><product_variant_id>754</product_variant_id><product_desc>SENSUAL SUBMISSION KIT</product_desc><variant_desc>SENSUAL SUBMISSION KIT</variant_desc><quantity>2</quantity><item_total>31.48</item_total></OrderItemRequest><OrderItemRequest><line_id>2</line_id><product_id>239</product_id><product_variant_id>239</product_variant_id><product_desc>G-SPOT VIBE AND LUBE</product_desc><variant_desc>G-SPOT VIBE AND LUBE</variant_desc><quantity>1</quantity><item_total>14.95</item_total></OrderItemRequest>"
2013-04-27 05:22:42.816888 wsdl: in serializeType: got a prefixed type: ArrayOfOrderItemRequest, http://phepartnerws/
2013-04-27 05:22:42.816904 wsdl: in getTypeDef: type=ArrayOfOrderItemRequest, ns=http://phepartnerws/
2013-04-27 05:22:42.816918 wsdl: in getTypeDef: have schema for namespace http://phepartnerws/
2013-04-27 05:22:42.816937 nusoap_xmlschema: <http://phepartnerws/> in getTypeDef, found complexType ArrayOfOrderItemRequest
2013-04-27 05:22:42.816954 wsdl: in getTypeDef: found type ArrayOfOrderItemRequest
2013-04-27 05:22:42.816968 wsdl: in serializeType: found typeDef
typeDef=array(6) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(23) "ArrayOfOrderItemRequest"
  ["typeClass"]=>
  string(11) "complexType"
  ["phpType"]=>
  string(6) "struct"
  ["simpleContent"]=>
  string(5) "false"
  ["compositor"]=>
  string(8) "sequence"
  ["elements"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["OrderItemRequest"]=>
    array(6) {
      ["minOccurs"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["maxOccurs"]=>
      string(9) "unbounded"
      ["name"]=>
      string(16) "OrderItemRequest"
      ["nillable"]=>
      string(4) "true"
      ["type"]=>
      string(37) "http://phepartnerws/:OrderItemRequest"
      ["form"]=>
      string(9) "qualified"
    }
  }
}
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817006 wsdl: in serializeType: uqType: ArrayOfOrderItemRequest, ns: http://phepartnerws/, phptype: struct, arrayType: 
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817022 wsdl: in serializeType: phpType is struct, but value is not an array
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817037 wsdl: in serializeType: returning: 
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817058 wsdl: in serializeType: name=CV_Code, type=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:string, use=literal, encodingStyle=, unqualified=qualified
value=string(3) "123"
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817080 wsdl: in serializeType: got a prefixed type: string, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817095 wsdl: in serializeType: type namespace indicates XML Schema or SOAP Encoding type
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817115 wsdl: in getTypeDef: type=string, ns=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817131 wsdl: in getTypeDef: do not have schema for namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817146 wsdl: in serializeType: returning: <CV_Code>123</CV_Code>
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817166 wsdl: in serializeType: name=ChallengeQuestion, type=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:string, use=literal, encodingStyle=, unqualified=qualified
value=string(0) ""
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817189 wsdl: in serializeType: got a prefixed type: string, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817203 wsdl: in serializeType: type namespace indicates XML Schema or SOAP Encoding type
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817222 wsdl: in getTypeDef: type=string, ns=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817238 wsdl: in getTypeDef: do not have schema for namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817252 wsdl: in serializeType: returning: <ChallengeQuestion></ChallengeQuestion>
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817273 wsdl: in serializeType: name=ChallengeAnswer, type=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:string, use=literal, encodingStyle=, unqualified=qualified
value=string(0) ""
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817294 wsdl: in serializeType: got a prefixed type: string, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817309 wsdl: in serializeType: type namespace indicates XML Schema or SOAP Encoding type
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817328 wsdl: in getTypeDef: type=string, ns=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817344 wsdl: in getTypeDef: do not have schema for namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817359 wsdl: in serializeType: returning: <ChallengeAnswer></ChallengeAnswer>
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817382 wsdl: in serializeType: name=localeSetting, type=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:string, use=literal, encodingStyle=, unqualified=qualified
value=string(0) ""
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817404 wsdl: in serializeType: got a prefixed type: string, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817419 wsdl: in serializeType: type namespace indicates XML Schema or SOAP Encoding type
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817438 wsdl: in getTypeDef: type=string, ns=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817454 wsdl: in getTypeDef: do not have schema for namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817469 wsdl: in serializeType: returning: <localeSetting></localeSetting>
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817492 wsdl: in serializeType: name=ignoreAddressValidation, type=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:boolean, use=literal, encodingStyle=, unqualified=qualified
value=string(1) "1"
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817514 wsdl: in serializeType: got a prefixed type: boolean, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817529 wsdl: in serializeType: type namespace indicates XML Schema or SOAP Encoding type
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817546 wsdl: in getTypeDef: type=boolean, ns=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817561 wsdl: in getTypeDef: do not have schema for namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817576 wsdl: in serializeType: returning: <ignoreAddressValidation>true</ignoreAddressValidation>
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817596 wsdl: in serializeType: name=auth_code, type=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:string, use=literal, encodingStyle=, unqualified=qualified
value=string(0) ""
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817618 wsdl: in serializeType: got a prefixed type: string, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817633 wsdl: in serializeType: type namespace indicates XML Schema or SOAP Encoding type
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817651 wsdl: in getTypeDef: type=string, ns=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817667 wsdl: in getTypeDef: do not have schema for namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817681 wsdl: in serializeType: returning: <auth_code></auth_code>
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817702 wsdl: in serializeType: name=affiliate_code, type=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:string, use=literal, encodingStyle=, unqualified=qualified
value=string(0) ""
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817723 wsdl: in serializeType: got a prefixed type: string, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817738 wsdl: in serializeType: type namespace indicates XML Schema or SOAP Encoding type
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817757 wsdl: in getTypeDef: type=string, ns=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817773 wsdl: in getTypeDef: do not have schema for namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817787 wsdl: in serializeType: returning: <affiliate_code></affiliate_code>
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817805 wsdl: in serializeType: returning: <oOrderRequest><RequestCredentials><CallerID>livereps</CallerID><Timestamp>2013-04-27T01:22:42-04:00</Timestamp><Token>1/kUrVDZmoYqbj1/PhCE4w==</Token></RequestCredentials><company></company><xml></xml><partnerID>livereps</partnerID><sourceCode></sourceCode><item_total>102.89</item_total><amount_total>122.89</amount_total><amount_tax>6.69</amount_tax><shipping_charge>20.00</shipping_charge><shipping_total>20.00</shipping_total><shipping_allowance>0</shipping_allowance><amount_ins>0</amount_ins><order_create_date>2013-04-27</order_create_date><amount_disc></amount_disc><bfirst>James</bfirst><blast>James</blast><baddr1>Jewell</baddr1><baddr2></baddr2><bcity>Cincinnati</bcity><bstate>OH</bstate><bcountry>US</bcountry><bzip>45255</bzip><sfirst>James</sfirst><slast>James</slast><saddr1>Jewell</saddr1><saddr2></saddr2><scity>Cincinnati</scity><sstate>OH</sstate><scountry>US</scountry><szip>45255</szip><carrier_code>UPS</carrier_code><dob>1970-01-01</dob><creditcard_number>5434651900577797</creditcard_number><card_type>M</card_type><card_expire_date>01/14</card_expire_date><Customer_Email>jamesnjewell@yahoo.com</Customer_Email><CV_Code>123</CV_Code><ChallengeQuestion></ChallengeQuestion><ChallengeAnswer></ChallengeAnswer><localeSetting></localeSetting><ignoreAddressValidation>true</ignoreAddressValidation><auth_code></auth_code><affiliate_code></affiliate_code></oOrderRequest>
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817823 wsdl: in serializeType: returning: <CreateOrder xmlns="http://phepartnerws/"><oOrderRequest><RequestCredentials><CallerID>livereps</CallerID><Timestamp>2013-04-27T01:22:42-04:00</Timestamp><Token>1/kUrVDZmoYqbj1/PhCE4w==</Token></RequestCredentials><company></company><xml></xml><partnerID>livereps</partnerID><sourceCode></sourceCode><item_total>102.89</item_total><amount_total>122.89</amount_total><amount_tax>6.69</amount_tax><shipping_charge>20.00</shipping_charge><shipping_total>20.00</shipping_total><shipping_allowance>0</shipping_allowance><amount_ins>0</amount_ins><order_create_date>2013-04-27</order_create_date><amount_disc></amount_disc><bfirst>James</bfirst><blast>James</blast><baddr1>Jewell</baddr1><baddr2></baddr2><bcity>Cincinnati</bcity><bstate>OH</bstate><bcountry>US</bcountry><bzip>45255</bzip><sfirst>James</sfirst><slast>James</slast><saddr1>Jewell</saddr1><saddr2></saddr2><scity>Cincinnati</scity><sstate>OH</sstate><scountry>US</scountry><szip>45255</szip><carrier_code>UPS</carrier_code><dob>1970-01-01</dob><creditcard_number>5434651900577797</creditcard_number><card_type>M</card_type><card_expire_date>01/14</card_expire_date><Customer_Email>jamesnjewell@yahoo.com</Customer_Email><CV_Code>123</CV_Code><ChallengeQuestion></ChallengeQuestion><ChallengeAnswer></ChallengeAnswer><localeSetting></localeSetting><ignoreAddressValidation>true</ignoreAddressValidation><auth_code></auth_code><affiliate_code></affiliate_code></oOrderRequest></CreateOrder>
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817840 wsdl: serializeRPCParameters returning: <CreateOrder xmlns="http://phepartnerws/"><oOrderRequest><RequestCredentials><CallerID>livereps</CallerID><Timestamp>2013-04-27T01:22:42-04:00</Timestamp><Token>1/kUrVDZmoYqbj1/PhCE4w==</Token></RequestCredentials><company></company><xml></xml><partnerID>livereps</partnerID><sourceCode></sourceCode><item_total>102.89</item_total><amount_total>122.89</amount_total><amount_tax>6.69</amount_tax><shipping_charge>20.00</shipping_charge><shipping_total>20.00</shipping_total><shipping_allowance>0</shipping_allowance><amount_ins>0</amount_ins><order_create_date>2013-04-27</order_create_date><amount_disc></amount_disc><bfirst>James</bfirst><blast>James</blast><baddr1>Jewell</baddr1><baddr2></baddr2><bcity>Cincinnati</bcity><bstate>OH</bstate><bcountry>US</bcountry><bzip>45255</bzip><sfirst>James</sfirst><slast>James</slast><saddr1>Jewell</saddr1><saddr2></saddr2><scity>Cincinnati</scity><sstate>OH</sstate><scountry>US</scountry><szip>45255</szip><carrier_code>UPS</carrier_code><dob>1970-01-01</dob><creditcard_number>5434651900577797</creditcard_number><card_type>M</card_type><card_expire_date>01/14</card_expire_date><Customer_Email>jamesnjewell@yahoo.com</Customer_Email><CV_Code>123</CV_Code><ChallengeQuestion></ChallengeQuestion><ChallengeAnswer></ChallengeAnswer><localeSetting></localeSetting><ignoreAddressValidation>true</ignoreAddressValidation><auth_code></auth_code><affiliate_code></affiliate_code></oOrderRequest></CreateOrder>
2013-04-27 05:22:42.817889 nusoap_client: got wsdl error: phpType is struct, but value is not an array: see debug output for details
```

I'm still fairly new to using soap/nusoap, but I do believe that the error is the xml value I am passing in directly.  If I remove the line `'orderItems' => $orderItemRequest,`, I do not get the error.  Is there any way to put multiple arrays with the same key into the same array?

Comment: In an array it is not possible to have the same key multiple times - it would not bee a key any longer. I'm not familiar with nusoap, so I dunno how they solve that, I can imagine two ways: Either have the key once and an array as its value containing the multiple elements or having an array of arrays of which each one conains a single entry with that key.

Comment: also you should not build XML your own but take a library that does the job for you. You can then create the array format that suits you best probably as well as you are creating the XML your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not how I would have expected it to work, but the below works:

```
$orderItemRequest = array();
$orderItemRequest['OrderItemRequest'] = array();
foreach ($item_cart as $product) {
    array_push(
        $orderItemRequest['OrderItemRequest'], array(
                'line_id' => $product['line_id'],
                'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
                'product_variant_id' => $product['product_variant_id'],
                'product_desc' => $product['product_desc'],
                'variant_desc' => $product['variant_desc'],
                'quantity' => $product['quantity'],
                'item_total' => $product['item_total']
        )
    );
}
```

The repeating object is not specified more than once (`OrderItemRequest`), but instead it is assigned multiple arrays.  That caused the object itself to repeat in the xml.

```
            <orderItems>
                <OrderItemRequest>
                    <line_id>0</line_id>
                    <product_id>A533</product_id>
                    <product_variant_id>A533</product_variant_id>
                    <product_desc>Description</product_desc>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <variant_desc>Description</variant_desc>
                    <item_total>9.98</item_total>
                </OrderItemRequest>
                <OrderItemRequest>
                    <line_id>1</line_id>
                    <product_id>239</product_id>
                    <product_variant_id>239</product_variant_id>
                    <product_desc>Description</product_desc>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <variant_desc>Description</variant_desc>
                    <item_total>14.95</item_total>
                </OrderItemR
```

Comment: Thank you! It indeed turns out that you will have to add a element to your parameters array which is keyed with the expected object name, this should contain an non-associative array with the data per array.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer from internet and it helps me a lot:

Imagine the request is going to look like this:

XML Diagram 1:

```
<CountBasketItems>
    <Basket>
        <fruits>
            <fruit>
                <name>Apple</name>
                <color>red</color>
            </fruit>
            <fruit>
                <name>Bananna</name>
                <color>yellow</color>
            </fruit>
            <fruit>
                <name>Apple</name>
                <color>green</color>
            </fruit>
        </fruits>
        <vegetables>
            <vegetable>
                <name>Orion</name>
                <color>yellow</color>
            </vegetable>
            <vegetable>
                <name>Carot</name>
                <color>orange</color>
            </vegetable>
            <vegetable>
                <name>Orion</name>
                <color>red</color>
            </vegetable>
        </vegetables>
    </Basket>
</CountBasketItems>
```

The real question is: how do I setup my parameter array to accommodate this. The answer:

```
$fruits = array();
$fruits[] = array(‘name’ => ‘Apple’, ‘color’ => ‘red’);
$fruits[] = array(‘name’ => ‘Bananna’, ‘color’ => ‘yellow’);
$fruits[] = array(‘name’ => ‘Apple’, ‘color’ => ‘green’);

$vegetables = array();
$vegetables[] = array(‘name’ => ‘Orion’, ‘color’ => ‘yellow’);
$vegetables[] = array(‘name’ => ‘Carrot’, ‘color’ => ‘orange’);
$vegetables[] = array(‘name’ => ‘Orion’, ‘color’ => ‘red’);

$basket = array ( ‘fruits’ => $fruits, ‘vegetables’ => $vegetables );
```

Here is what $basket looks like when I run print_r($basket):

```
Array
(
[fruits] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[name] => Apple
[color] => red
)
[1] => Array
(
[name] => Bananna
[color] => yellow
)
[2] => Array
(
[name] => Apple
[color] => green
)
)
[vegetables] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[name] => Orion
[color] => yellow
)
[1] => Array
(
[name] => Carrot
[color] => orange
)
[2] => Array
(
[name] => Orion
[color] => red
)
)
)
```

Here is a complete example, server and client:

server.php:

```
configureWSDL('maxfruitwsdl', 'urn:maxfruitwsdl');
// Put the WSDL schema types in the namespace with the tns prefix
$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = 'urn:maxfruitwsdl';
// Register the data structures used by the service
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
'Fruit',
'complexType',
'struct',
'all',
'',
array(
'name' => array('name' => 'name', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
'color' => array('name' => 'color', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
)
);
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
'Fruits',
'complexType',
'array',
'',
'SOAP-ENC:Array',
array(),
array(
array('ref' => 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType', 'wsdl:arrayType' => 'tns:Fruit[]')
),
'tns:Fruit'
);
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
'Vegetable',
'complexType',
'struct',
'all',
'',
array(
'name' => array('name' => 'name', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
'color' => array('name' => 'color', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
)
);
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
'Vegetables',
'complexType',
'array',
'',
'SOAP-ENC:Array',
array(),
array(
array('ref' => 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType', 'wsdl:arrayType' => 'tns:Vegetable[]')
),
'tns:Vegetable'
);

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
'Basket',
'complexType',
'struct',
'all',
'',
array(
'fruits' => array('name' => 'fruits', 'type' => 'tns:Fruits'),
'vegetables' => array('name' => 'vegetables', 'type' => 'tns:Vegetables'),
)
);

// Register the method to expose
$server->register('CountBasketItems', // method name
array('Basket' => 'tns:Basket'), // input parameters
array('return' => 'xsd:int'), // output parameters
'urn:maxfruitwsdl', // namespace
'urn:maxfruitwsdl#CountBasketItems', // soapaction
'rpc', // style
'encoded', // use
'Return the number of items in the basket' // documentation
);

function CountBasketItems( $basket )
{
return count($basket['fruits']) + count($basket['vegetables']);
}

// This returns the result
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

client.php

```
$fruits[] = array('name' => 'Bananna', 'color' => 'yellow');
$fruits[] = array('name' => 'Apple', 'color' => 'green');

$vegetables = array();
$vegetables[] = array('name' => 'Orion', 'color' => 'yellow');
$vegetables[] = array('name' => 'Carrot', 'color' => 'orange');
$vegetables[] = array('name' => 'Orion', 'color' => 'red');

$basket = array ( 'fruits' => $fruits, 'vegetables' => $vegetables );

print "My Basket:";
echo str_replace(' ', '  ', nl2br(htmlspecialchars(print_r($basket, true))));

// Create the client instance
$client = new soapclient('http://www.modphp.org/nusoap/server.php?wsdl', true);
// Check for an error
$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
// Display the error
echo 'Constructor error' . $err . '';
// At this point, you know the call that follows will fail
}

// Create the proxy
$proxy = $client->getProxy();

// Call the SOAP method
$result = $proxy->CountBasketItems($basket);

// Check for a fault
if ($proxy->fault) {
echo 'Faul';
print_r($result);
echo '';
} else {
// Check for errors
$err = $proxy->getError();
if ($err) {
// Display the error
echo '
Error' . $err . '';
} else {
// Display the result
echo 'Result of CountBasketItems';
print_r($result);
echo '';
}
}
// Display the request and response
echo 'Request';
echo str_replace(' ', ' ', nl2br(htmlspecialchars($proxy->request, ENT_QUOTES)));
echo 'Response';
echo str_replace(' ', ' ', nl2br(htmlspecialchars($proxy->response, ENT_QUOTES)));
// Display the debug messages
```

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like  you don't have an header base element to your xml:

```
$orderItemRequest = "";

$orderItemRequest .= "<orderItems>"; //main element comes here

foreach($requestArray as $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        $orderItemRequest .= $comma."<$key>";

        foreach ($val as $key2 => $val2) {
            $orderItemRequest .= "<$key2>$val2</$key2>";
        }

        $orderItemRequest .= "</$key>";
    }
}

$orderItemRequest .= "</orderItems>"; // closing main element comes here
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is because this is not all of the xml.  nusoap actually created the XML using the arrays passed to it as a parameter.  My issue is that I cannot create this part as an array because it would have the same key, which of course is not allowed.